several custom positioned labels for MUI Bar Chart
I have a MUI Bar Chart, but I need some custom labels at a certain position. This is the design I want to develop:

so far I'm at this point and bar chart is rendered:

Unfortunately I cannot find a documentation where described how to put a label on top of the whole stacked bar. I can only find barLabel where a label is centered in each single segment of a stack. Furthermore I need to put an icon inside the stack at the bottom.
